# In Pandas Series, a tuple of more than one element can be passed as a argument to series.str.startswith( )?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose i have a series of names as given below :

```
0         Mr. Ram
1    Miss. Rashmi
2      Mrs. Divya
3     Master Ravi
4     Miss. Kirti
5        Mr. Ajay
6     Mrs. Sheela
7    Miss. Poonam
dtype: object
```

Now if i have to count number of females in the Series, i have to count the names which starts from Mrs. or either Miss. Now if i write code like this :

```
ser.str.startswith(("Miss.", "Mrs.")).sum()
```

It gives the correct answer. Please notice that a tuple ("Miss.", "Mrs.") is passed as an argument to startswith method . Is it a valid practice to pass a tuple of multiple items as an argument to pandas `series.str.startswith()?`

The pandas official documentation only suggest to pass a single item to the above said method.
Kindly spread light on it.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) for that function note that it's:

> Equivalent to str.startswith().

If we check the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) for `str.startswith`, it contains the sentence:

> prefix can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for

So yes, Pandas documents it as only taking a String, but the official docs indicate that it also takes tuples.

---

If we check the source, `ser.str.startswith` appears to be defined as:

```
f = lambda x: x.startswith(pat)
return _na_map(f, arr, na, dtype=np.dtype(bool))
```

I say "appears", because wow, what a difficult read that module is. `x` appears to be the `string` module itself, and they have some kind of `CachedAccessor` wrapper system in place for caching module accesses? Or something?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good one but would like to suggest you using regex with `pandas.Series.count()` and `sum()` it to get number of females.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {0: 'Mr. Ram',1:'Miss. Rashmi',2:'Mrs. Divya',3:'Master Ravi'}
>>> s = pd.Series(d)
>>> s
0         Mr. Ram
1    Miss. Rashmi
2      Mrs. Divya
3    Master Ravi
dtype: object
>>> s.str.count(r'(^Mrs)|(^Miss)').sum()
2
```

Try this out!